# sql search if value is from single column range like 30 to 100 or value can be only 35

Tags: mysql, sql

this is how table looks like

```
id  value 
1    9
2    10 
3    10.5 
4    11
5    11.5
6    12 to 30
7    30 to 60
```

in where condition if i pass 10 it will return id 2 
now question is if i pass 20 then how do i get id  6
how can i achieve this in mysql??
thanks in advance

Comment: You really need to fix your table to have two columns, `minvalue` and `maxvalue`.  Don't store numbers as strings.

Comment: Is that what you have in the column? `12 to 30`?

Comment: Don't store data like that, have one column for min value and another column for max value. Like 7, 30, 60.

Comment: i know that but in such conditions i have to do it that's why otherwise i will store it in minval and maxval column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using SUBSTRING_INDEX :

```
SELECT id
FROM YourTable
WHERE value = YourNumber
      OR (YourNumber between SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,'to',1)
                    and SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,'to',-1))
```

The OR part will return the number before the **to** and after the **to** and check if the number is between them